# jax-ws endpoint gets blocked writting on socket since Java 8 upgrade

Tags: java, jax-ws, java-8, streamwriter, chunked-encoding

We use JAX-WS implementation with JAXB for webservices, we have recently upgraded to jdk 8, since then we are having an issue when our endpoint is sending the responses. After digging into it, I realized that the endpoint thread gets blocked when writing on the socket.

Here is thread stack trace from server side when the execution is blocked, as you can see it gets blocked when writing. The client side gets also blocked reading until reaches a timeout.

```
Daemon Thread [jaxws-engine-WSEndpointSever::WSEnpointServer-3-thread-1] (Suspended)    
    owns: Object  (id=8288) 
    owns: Request$WriteStream  (id=8289)    
    SocketDispatcher.write0(FileDescriptor, long, int) line: not available [native method] [local variables unavailable]    
    SocketDispatcher.write(FileDescriptor, long, int) line: 51  
    IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(FileDescriptor, ByteBuffer, long, NativeDispatcher) line: 93   
    IOUtil.write(FileDescriptor, ByteBuffer, long, NativeDispatcher) line: 65   
    SocketChannelImpl.write(ByteBuffer) line: 470   
    Request$WriteStream.write(byte[], int, int) line: 391   
    ChunkedOutputStream.writeChunk() line: 125 [local variables unavailable]    
    ChunkedOutputStream.flush() line: 159 [local variables unavailable] 
    PlaceholderOutputStream.flush() line: 449 [local variables unavailable] 
    ServerConnectionImpl$1(FilterOutputStream).flush() line: 140 [local variables unavailable]  
    UTF8OutputStreamWriter.flush() line: 138    
    XMLStreamWriterImpl.flush() line: 397   
    XMLStreamWriterFactory$HasEncodingWriter(XMLStreamWriterFilter).flush() line: 56    
    SAAJMessage.writeTo(XMLStreamWriter) line: 365  
    MessageWrapper.writeTo(XMLStreamWriter) line: 206   
    StreamSOAP11Codec(StreamSOAPCodec).encode(Packet, OutputStream) line: 129   
    SOAPBindingCodec.encode(Packet, OutputStream) line: 227 
    ServerAdapter(HttpAdapter).encodePacket(Packet, WSHTTPConnection, Codec) line: 474  
    HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter, Packet, WSHTTPConnection, Codec) line: 90   
    HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(WSHTTPConnection) line: 716  
    ServerAdapter(HttpAdapter).handle(WSHTTPConnection) line: 260   
    WSHttpHandler.handleExchange(HttpExchange) line: 98 
    WSHttpHandler.access$000(WSHttpHandler, HttpExchange) line: 47  
    WSHttpHandler$HttpHandlerRunnable.run() line: 122   
    ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1142  
    ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 617   
    Thread.run() line: 745
```

This is happening in a random circumstances, when the responses are short it barely happens but it happens very frequently with large responses.

Is there anything new in java 8 that we should be aware?

Here is how it is basically published the webservice

**Server side**

```
        Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.create(inServiceImpl );
        endpoint.setExecutor( m_threadPoolExecutor );

        SOAPBinding binding = (SOAPBinding) endpoint.getBinding();


        List<Handler> handlerChain = new LinkedList<Handler>();
        handlerChain.add( new SOAPTraceHandler( jaxEndopoint.getEndPointURL(),jaxEndopoint.getService() ) );
        binding.setHandlerChain( handlerChain );


        // publish the endpoint and make available.
        endpoint.publish( jaxEndopoint.getEndPointURL() );
```

**Client side**

```
    m_service = proxy.getPort( Service.class );

    BindingProvider binding = (BindingProvider) m_service;
    Map<String, Object> ctxt = binding.getRequestContext();
    ctxt.put(JAXWSProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, 50000);

    //run method.
    m_service.runMethod(Payload);
```

Could it be related with the Chunked transfer enconding?
I haven't found a way to disable chunked encoding for the response,  is it possible to disable it?

I've also tried to use a jetty server as container using the WSServlet, then i go the following 
traces:

```
nov 10, 2014 4:20:14 EM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate doGet
SEVERE: caught throwable
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: com.sun.istack.SAXException2: timeout
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: timeout
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sun.istack.SAXException2: timeout
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: timeout]
at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:322)
at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:142)
at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:108)
at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:258)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.encodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:320)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:454)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:135)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:129)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:160)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:75)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:366)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

> Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
>    - with linked exception:
>   [com.sun.istack.SAXException2: com.sun.istack.SAXException2: timeout
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: timeout
>   javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sun.istack.SAXException2: timeout
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: timeout]

Your help would be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Regards.